# Using Generic Type DTO In ServiceStack Request

Tags: rest, generics, servicestack

I was wondering if it's possible to use a Templated DTO requested of the type public class

```
RequestDTO<T, U>       where T : class        where U : class
{
    public T ContextRequest { get; set; }

    public U Request { get; set; }
}
```

And pass it to my service's request...

I've tried a simple example of type

```
public class MyContext
{
//removed some fields  
    public int IdUser {get;set;}
}

public class MyType1Request
{
    public int IdRequest {get;set;}
}

public class MyType2Request
{
    public DateTime  SomeReallyImportantDate { get; set; }
}

public class UtenteService : Service
{
    public UtenteService()
    {
    }


    public string Any(RequestDTO<MyContext,MyType1Request> request)
    {
        return string.Format("User:{0} - IDRequest: {1}", request.ContextRequest.IdUser, request.Request.IDRequest);
    }

    public object Any(RequestDTO<MyContext, MyType2Request> request)
    {
        return string.Format("Utente:{0} - Data : {1}", request.ContextRequest.IDUtente, request.Request.DataLavorativa);
    }
```

But I got this as far I try to access to the service

```
Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

Another solution is to implement in each my DTO Request object a IContext (and maybe IContextExt IContextSpecificManner) into the request object...but I would prefer to use the first approach

Thanks

Comment: Generic DTO's are not supported, it must be a uniquely-named, concrete Request DTO.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK - This should work. The only thing that I am missing here is, you need to register route in apphost like:

```
Routes.Add>("/Utente/{IdUser}/{IdRequest}")
```

Comment: Hello Prashant, I don't know in real case my ContextRequest has more different parameters... and in some case I also have a derived type of the base ContextRequest .... I don't think I can put as {IdUser} a collection of parameters...

Comment: I Agree, You have to register different routes for each of your service. I was trying to demonstrate that using your current example.